# How can I use Shopify APIs to run code on the client side of the customer, i.e the storefront?

Tags: shopify, shopify-api, shopify-storefront-api

I want to run a javascript script on the storefront on a shopify store, the script should take the query parameters in the link and store them in a cookie making an api request to cloudflare workers.

I am very confused about how to go this. I tried making a shopify app extension using web pixel but I couldn't really understand its working and where can I input the script